# Meteor React Tutorial Expected string, got object

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

Hi guys so I got to step 9 by following this tutorial https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/security-with-methods

So i've written all the methods with their checks however I get errors like Exception while invoking method 'tasks.remove' Error: Match error: Expected string, got object

Here are my written codes 
This is the tasks.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
import { check } from 'meteor/check'

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks')

Meteor.methods({
  'tasks.insert' (text) {
    check(text, String)

    // Make sure the user is logged in before insterting a task
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized')
    }

    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      owner: this.userId,
      username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username
    })
  }, // tasks.insert
  'tasks.remove' (taskId) {
    check(taskId, String)

    Tasks.remove(taskId)
  },
  'tasks.setChecked' (taskId, setChecked) {
    check(taskId, String)
    check(setChecked, Boolean)

    Tasks.update(taskId, { $set: { checked: setChecked } })
  }
})
```

And this is the Task.jsx

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
// import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js'

// Task component - represents a single todo item
export default class Task extends Component {
toggleChecked () {
  // Set the checked value to the opposite of its current value
  Meteor.call('tasks.setChecked',this.props.task._id, !this.props.task.checked)
}

deleteThisTask () {
  Meteor.call('tasks.remove', this.props.task._id)
}
  render () {
    // Give tasks a different className when they are checked off,
    // so that we can style them nicely
    const taskClassName = this.props.task.checked ? 'checked' : ''
    return (
      <li className={taskClassName}>
        <button className="delete" onClick={this.deleteThisTask.bind(this)}>
          &times;
        </button>

        <input
          type="checkbox"
          readOnly
          checked={this.props.task.checked}
          onClick={this.toggleChecked.bind(this)}
        />

        <span className="text">
          <strong>{this.props.task.username}</strong>:{this.props.task.text}
        </span>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

Task.propTypes = {
  // This component gets the task to dipslay through a React prop.
  // We can use propTypes to indicate it is required
  task: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

What's the problem my written code seems to be identical with the tutorials code, why then do I get these errors? I got the same error for the update method.

**EDIT: After commenting the checks and doing the later steps of the tutorial and then enabling the checks makes them work... but I am not sure which part made them to work**

Comment: In ```tasks.remove (taskId)``` function, can you do a console.log(taskId) and see if you're actually getting an object? Also, where is this ```taskId``` coming into context from?

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154329/5978355)

Comment: @DzhakharUkhaev at the end of the tutorial it works with the check(taskId, String) and if I change it to object I get the opposite error that it expects string

Answer (score 0):

The `check` function is expecting a String because you passed `String` as a parameter for checking. But your React `Task` component is expecting Object.

```
Task.propTypes = {
  task: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Just try

```
'tasks.remove' (taskId) {
    check(taskId, Object)

    Tasks.remove(taskId)
},
```

instead of

```
'tasks.remove' (taskId) {
    check(taskId, String)

    Tasks.remove(taskId)
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It still gives error with 'Object'. Try concerting input with javascript String() function -

```
    'tasks.remove'(taskId) {
    check(String(taskId), String);

    Tasks.remove(taskId);
  },
  'tasks.setChecked'(taskId, setChecked) {
    check(String(taskId), String);
    check(setChecked, Boolean);

    Tasks.update(taskId, { $set: { checked: setChecked } });
  },
```